# Convert .mtl file in bytes

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, uwp

How can I convert `.mtl` file in bytes on UWP? It is my code now:

```
var bytesMtl = new byte[0];           

using (var streamMtl = await mtl.OpenReadAsync())
{
    bytes = new byte[streamMtl.Size];
    using (var reader = new DataReader(streamMtl))
    {
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)streamMtl.Size);
        reader.ReadBytes(bytesMtl);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code?  If it's not working please explain how it's not working

Comment: This code doing convert only .obj file. With .mtl file it doesn't work.

Comment: Again, 'doesn't work' - what does that mean?  Please explain fully

Comment: When I doing convert .obj file with help this code, I get the bytes array for .obj file {byte[254]}.
When I doing convert .mtl file with help this code, I get the bytes array for .mtl file {byte[0]}.
I don't know, how explain differently. Thanks!

Comment: That information is what was needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created two `byte` arrays: `bytesMtl` and `bytes`. You initialize the `bytes` with the right size (`streamMtl.Size`) but you then read the bytes into `bytesMtl` which is has zero length.

You should do the following:

```
var bytesMtl = null;           

using (var streamMtl = await mtl.OpenReadAsync())
{
    bytesMtl = new byte[streamMtl.Size];
    using (var reader = new DataReader(streamMtl))
    {
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)streamMtl.Size);
        reader.ReadBytes(bytesMtl);
    }
}
```